# Debugging both Java and native C++ code using Eclipse NDK plugin

Tags: android, windows, debugging, android-ndk

I'm trying out the new official Eclipse NDK plugin on Windows. After solving problems with NDK_MODULE_PATH (which were the only problems, surprisingly) the "Debug as Android native application" configuration works as intended. However, it only hits native code breakpoint while I want to debug Java as well. Is it possible to edit this configuration so that Java breakpoints are also hit?

Comment: how did you manage to debug it as a native app ? do i really need to have cygwin for this ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I believe you do since ndk-gdb is only available as sh-script.

Comment: are you sure? also , what if i use linux ? will it work out of the box ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: It worked on Windows so it should on Linux, but I didn't try yet.

Comment: thanks. i think cygwin is used to emulate linux/unix for the debugging , so if you use linux, you don't need an extra tool to install.